# batch string contains operation optimization?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search, batch-file

I have 2 sets of string, A and B. 
The problem I want to solve is to compute how many strings in set B contains ANY single string in set A. for instance:
A: "a","b"
B: "abc", "dsf", "aqc", "yyy", "xxx", "bbb"
the result is 3 ("abc","aqc","bbb")

unfortunately, set A and set B are very large in my case, say, set A have millions of strings, set B have billions of strings. So I have to take millions*billions ‘indexof’ operations in Java language. the algorithm of the complexity is O(m*n).

is there any optimization algorithms I can use to make it faster?

Comment: Just noting that even though the best algorithms worst case is m*n, this problem is parallelizable.

Comment: If set `A` always contains a single character, this can be achieved in `O(n)` where n is the size of set `B`. Otherwise it is `O(m*n)` as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a database search and a coffee break is common practice.

But let's see.

Using sets of letters:

- Map every letter to a prime, most frequent letter first: e 2, t 3, o 5, i 7, ...
- Calculate the product of all letter primes for strings in A and B.
- Now candidates in B are those that are dividable by any element in A.
- This might reduce the mapping of likely candidates by a huge factor.

Using search patterns (trees of letters of terms in A):

- This is a bit like making a regex pattern "(a|b)" but then very large. This pattern can be compiled and run against every word. Not sure whether this is a speed up.

And furthermore use Java 8 with its parallel streams, in blocks of 1000 from A and 1000 from B.